# Juypter note book - The Text part is not getting printed

Tags: python

I can able to scrape text from the following website. https://scrapsfromtheloft.com/2020/04/25/chris-d-elia-white-male-black-comic-transcript/

I used the following code in Jypyter notebook,

```
 import requests
    import bs4
    import pickle
    
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
    def url_to_transcript(url):
        page = requests.get(url).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
        text = [p.text for p in soup.find(class_="post-content").find_all('p')]
        print(url)
        return text

urls = ['https://scrapsfromtheloft.com/2020/04/25/chris-d-elia-white-male-black-comic-transcript/']

writer = ['chris']

    for i in urls:
        transcript=url_to_transcript(i)
        print(transcript)
```

After **scraping** the text from the website, I used this code to pickle the file.

```
for i, c in enumerate(writer):
    with open("transcripts/" + c + ".txt", "wb") as file:
        pickle.dump("transcripts[i]", file)
```

But when I checked the text file that was stored, there wasn't available the text I **scraped**, but just these two words alone €X   transcripts[i]q .

[image]

I am totally a newbie here so I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I just want the anaconda to print the text I extract from a website in the directory. Please clarify me. Thanks

Comment: Why use pickle in the first place? _I just want the anaconda to print the text I extract from a website in the directory._ I'm not sure I understand what Anaconda has to do with this particular issue. As an aside, it's best to pass the result of `Request.content` to BeautifulSoup, not `Request.text`.

Comment: Note that `"transcripts[i]"` is a _string_, not an element of some `transcripts` object.

Answer (score 0):

While your question doesn't show how this variable is generated, assuming `transcripts` is a list of lists containing text, then see the difference in the following output:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> transcripts = [["first_{}".format(i), "second_{}".format(i)] for i in range(3)]
>>> transcripts
[['first_0', 'second_0'], ['first_1', 'second_1'], ['first_2', 'second_2']]
>>> i=0
>>> pickle.loads(pickle.dumps("transcripts[i]"))
'transcripts[i]'
>>> pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(transcripts[i]))
['first_0', 'second_0']
>>>
```

In the first call, pickle simply pickles the text "transcripts[i]", while in the second (without quotes), it will pickle the value referenced by `transcript` in position `i`.

Please note that there's no magic in python that transforms singular names to plural, so you'll need explicitly declare/populate it, like so:

```
transcripts = []
for i in urls:
    transcript=url_to_transcript(i)
    print(transcript)
    transcripts.append(transcript)
```

If your code did not explicitly declare `transcripts`, then enclosing it with quotation marks would solve the `NameError` exception, but probably not the way you intended it to.